# Is it Possible to use the Result of Callout1 in Callout2?

Tags: apex, callout

I need to generate an access token with an HTTP callout and make use of that access token in another HTTP callout. These 2 HTTP callouts are future methods being called inside a Scheduled class. Is it possible to make use of the result from Callout1 for my callout2?

Comment: Why Callout1 and Callout2 are different future method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not in this case, because you can't even be sure of the order the two future calls are going to be executed. You're going to want to put both callouts inside of one `@future` method and just call that one from the scheduled code.

Comment: I actually wasn't aware of whether the order was maintained, good to know!

Comment: Actually, [this document](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Asynchronous_Processing_in_Force_com) explains it better. I think there are some possible situations where f2 might beat f1 out of the gate, depending on a very specific set of circumstances. So ignore my previous comment. That said, it's probably *very very rare* that this happens... I've never observed it before.

Comment: I've always treated them like operator precedence in a new language, and don't assume anything :)

Comment: Never thought it's okay to put 2 HTTP requests in one future method. It worked. Thanks for the suggestion.